# Creating a New Button in existing Source Code?

Tags: android, eclipse, button

http://www.itechcode.com/2012/03/18/create-calculator-in-android-programming/

Im using his source code but it seems very different than the "Beginner Level" Programming I have been use to i.e. creating new project, modifying layout, referencing in main.java, etc.

I'm trying to use his source code and modify/create new operations and maybe add a activity. I would usually know how to do most of that stuff if it wasn't laid out differently. Thank You!

```
    package com.pragmatouch.calculator;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Stack;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class main extends Activity {
        GridView mKeypadGrid;
        TextView userInputText;
        TextView memoryStatText;

        Stack<String> mInputStack;
        Stack<String> mOperationStack;

        KeypadAdapter mKeypadAdapter;
        TextView mStackText;
        boolean resetInput = false;
        boolean hasFinalResult = false;

        String mDecimalSeperator;
        double memoryValue = Double.NaN;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat
                    .getInstance();
            char decimalSeperator = currencyFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols()
                    .getDecimalSeparator();
            mDecimalSeperator = Character.toString(decimalSeperator);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // Create the stack
            mInputStack = new Stack<String>();
            mOperationStack = new Stack<String>();

            // Get reference to the keypad button GridView
            mKeypadGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdButtons);

            // Get reference to the user input TextView
            userInputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
            userInputText.setText("0");

            memoryStatText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMemory);
            memoryStatText.setText("");

            mStackText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStack);

            // Create Keypad Adapter
            mKeypadAdapter = new KeypadAdapter(this);

            // Set adapter of the keypad grid
            mKeypadGrid.setAdapter(mKeypadAdapter);

            // Set button click listener of the keypad adapter
            mKeypadAdapter.setOnButtonClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button btn = (Button) v;


                    // Get the KeypadButton value which is used to identify the
                    // keypad button from the Button's tag
                    KeypadButton keypadButton = (KeypadButton) btn.getTag();

                    // Process keypad button
                    ProcessKeypadInput(keypadButton);
                }
            });

            mKeypadGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                }
            });

        }

        private void ProcessKeypadInput(KeypadButton keypadButton) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, keypadButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String text = keypadButton.getText().toString();
            String currentInput = userInputText.getText().toString();

            int currentInputLen = currentInput.length();
            String evalResult = null;
            double userInputValue = Double.NaN;

            switch (keypadButton) {
            case BACKSPACE: // Handle backspace
                // If has operand skip backspace
                if (resetInput)
                    return;

                int endIndex = currentInputLen - 1;

                // There is one character at input so reset input to 0
                if (endIndex < 1) {
                    userInputText.setText("0");
                }
                // Trim last character of the input text
                else {
                    userInputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(0, endIndex));
                }
                break;
            case SIGN: // Handle -/+ sign
                // input has text and is different than initial value 0
                if (currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput != "0") {
                    // Already has (-) sign. Remove that sign
                    if (currentInput.charAt(0) == '-') {
                        userInputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(1,
                                currentInputLen));
                    }
                    // Prepend (-) sign
                    else {
                        userInputText.setText("-" + currentInput.toString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case CE: // Handle clear input
                userInputText.setText("0");
                break;
            case C: // Handle clear input and stack
                userInputText.setText("0");
                clearStacks();
                break;
            case DECIMAL_SEP: // Handle decimal seperator
                if (hasFinalResult || resetInput) {
                    userInputText.setText("0" + mDecimalSeperator);
                    hasFinalResult = false;
                    resetInput = false;
                } else if (currentInput.contains("."))
                    return;
                else
                    userInputText.append(mDecimalSeperator);
                break;
            case DIV:
            case PLUS:
            case MINUS:
            case MULTIPLY:
                if (resetInput) {
                    mInputStack.pop();
                    mOperationStack.pop();
                } else {
                    if (currentInput.charAt(0) == '-') {
                        mInputStack.add("(" + currentInput + ")");
                    } else {
                        mInputStack.add(currentInput);
                    }
                    mOperationStack.add(currentInput);
                }

                mInputStack.add(text);
                mOperationStack.add(text);

                dumpInputStack();
                evalResult = evaluateResult(false);
                if (evalResult != null)
                    userInputText.setText(evalResult);

                resetInput = true;
                break;
            case CALCULATE:
                if (mOperationStack.size() == 0)
                    break;

                mOperationStack.add(currentInput);
                evalResult = evaluateResult(true);
                if (evalResult != null) {
                    clearStacks();
                    userInputText.setText(evalResult);
                    resetInput = false;
                    hasFinalResult = true;
                }
                break;
            case M_ADD: // Add user input value to memory buffer
                userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
                if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                    return;
                if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                    memoryValue = 0;
                memoryValue += userInputValue;
                displayMemoryStat();

                hasFinalResult = true;

                break;
            case M_REMOVE: // Subtract user input value to memory buffer
                userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
                if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                    return;
                if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                    memoryValue = 0;
                memoryValue -= userInputValue;
                displayMemoryStat();
                hasFinalResult = true;
                break;
            case MC: // Reset memory buffer to 0
                memoryValue = Double.NaN;
                displayMemoryStat();
                break;
            case MR: // Read memoryBuffer value
                if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                    return;
                userInputText.setText(doubleToString(memoryValue));
                displayMemoryStat();
                break;
            case MS: // Set memoryBuffer value to user input
                userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
                if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                    return;
                memoryValue = userInputValue;
                displayMemoryStat();
                hasFinalResult = true;
                break;
            case PRGM: 
            break;
            default:
                if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0))) {
                    if (currentInput.equals("0") || resetInput || hasFinalResult) {
                        userInputText.setText(text);
                        resetInput = false;
                        hasFinalResult = false;
                    } else {
                        userInputText.append(text);
                        resetInput = false;
                    }

                }
                break;

            }

        }

        private void clearStacks() {
            mInputStack.clear();
            mOperationStack.clear();
            mStackText.setText("");
        }

        private void dumpInputStack() {
            Iterator<String> it = mInputStack.iterator();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                CharSequence iValue = it.next();
                sb.append(iValue);

            }

            mStackText.setText(sb.toString());
        }

        private String evaluateResult(boolean requestedByUser) {
            if ((!requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 4)
                    || (requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 3))
                return null;

            String left = mOperationStack.get(0);
            String operator = mOperationStack.get(1);
            String right = mOperationStack.get(2);
            String tmp = null;
            if (!requestedByUser)
                tmp = mOperationStack.get(3);

            double leftVal = Double.parseDouble(left.toString());
            double rightVal = Double.parseDouble(right.toString());
            double result = Double.NaN;

            if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.DIV.getText())) {
                result = leftVal / rightVal;
            } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MULTIPLY.getText())) {
                result = leftVal * rightVal;

            } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.PLUS.getText())) {
                result = leftVal + rightVal;
            } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MINUS.getText())) {
                result = leftVal - rightVal;

            }

            String resultStr = doubleToString(result);
            if (resultStr == null)
                return null;

            mOperationStack.clear();
            if (!requestedByUser) {
                mOperationStack.add(resultStr);
                mOperationStack.add(tmp);
            }

            return resultStr;
        }

        private String doubleToString(double value) {
            if (Double.isNaN(value))
                return null;

            long longVal = (long) value;
            if (longVal == value)
                return Long.toString(longVal);
            else
                return Double.toString(value);

        }

        private double tryParseUserInput() {
            String inputStr = userInputText.getText().toString();
            double result = Double.NaN;
            try {
                result = Double.parseDouble(inputStr);

            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            }
            return result;

        }

        private void displayMemoryStat() {
            if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue)) {
                memoryStatText.setText("");
            } else {
                memoryStatText.setText("M = " + doubleToString(memoryValue));
            }
        }

    }
```

ENUM:

```
package com.pragmatouch.calculator;

public enum KeypadButton {
    MC("MC",KeypadButtonCategory.MEMORYBUFFER)
    , MR("MR",KeypadButtonCategory.MEMORYBUFFER)
    , MS("MS",KeypadButtonCategory.MEMORYBUFFER)
    , M_ADD("M+",KeypadButtonCategory.MEMORYBUFFER)
    , M_REMOVE("M-",KeypadButtonCategory.MEMORYBUFFER)
    , BACKSPACE("<-",KeypadButtonCategory.CLEAR)
    , CE("CE",KeypadButtonCategory.CLEAR)
    , C("C",KeypadButtonCategory.CLEAR)
    , ZERO("0",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , ONE("1",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , TWO("2",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , THREE("3",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , FOUR("4",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , FIVE("5",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , SIX("6",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , SEVEN("7",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , EIGHT("8",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , NINE("9",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , PLUS(" + ",KeypadButtonCategory.OPERATOR)
    , MINUS(" - ",KeypadButtonCategory.OPERATOR)
    , MULTIPLY(" * ",KeypadButtonCategory.OPERATOR)
    , DIV(" / ",KeypadButtonCategory.OPERATOR)
    , RECIPROC("1/x",KeypadButtonCategory.OTHER)
    , DECIMAL_SEP(",",KeypadButtonCategory.OTHER)
    , SIGN("±",KeypadButtonCategory.OTHER)
    , SQRT("SQRT",KeypadButtonCategory.OTHER)
    , PERCENT("%",KeypadButtonCategory.OTHER)
    , CALCULATE("=",KeypadButtonCategory.RESULT)
    , PRGM("PRGM",KeypadButtonCategory.PRGM)
    , DUMMY("",KeypadButtonCategory.DUMMY);

    CharSequence mText; // Display Text
    KeypadButtonCategory mCategory;

    KeypadButton(CharSequence text,KeypadButtonCategory category) {
        mText = text;
        mCategory = category;
    }

    public CharSequence getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

package com.pragmatouch.calculator;

```
public enum KeypadButtonCategory {
    MEMORYBUFFER
    , NUMBER
    , OPERATOR
    , DUMMY
    , CLEAR
    , RESULT
    , OTHER
    , PRGM
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Add a new button to the layout ? Why cant do that by going to the `layout.xml` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because you aren't asking a clear question.  Try rephrasing so we know what you want to do.  Just creating a button is as simple as new Button(), then adding it to a layout.  But I don't think that's really what you want to know.

Comment: I want to add/modify buttons in the gridview to my own liking but I am not entirely familiar with enums, adapters, etc. So I was hoping someone could have a simple answer on how to add buttons, modify their size, etc. Thank you for your time!

Comment: checkout my answer. I hope it can send you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I have a great answer for you. I recently wanted to create my own button in android but I wanted to do it in a simple way. Follow these steps and in a few minutes I will post pictures.

1) create a new layout. start with a `LinearLayout`. Nest a `FramedLayout` and another `LinearLayout` inside of it.

2) then add  a `TextView` to it. This is where practice makes perfect. Play around with the attributes. Learn what they do. when you have the general information of how you want your button to be display go to the next step.

3) what your are going to do is include this in another view as a button. You can use a specific attribute to make it look like a button as well.

Give me a few minutes and I will post some code and a picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/CBN_LinearLayout"
style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CBV_texview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/checkorder"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/CBV_imageView1"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:contentDescription="@string/redcirclenotify"
            android:src="@drawable/rednotify"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CBV_textview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CBV_textview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/blankstring" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CBV_textview4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/blankstring" />
</LinearLayout>
```

when you add it to another view as a button you use:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/MI_checkorder"
        style="android:buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/custombtnview"
        android:background="@style/AppTheme"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
```

The important part of this is setting the Style for the root `LinearLayout` to `@android:style/Widget.Button`

Once this is done it will look like a button and work like a button.

Below is an image of the final product:

[image: Custom Android Button]

another part of your question. Adjust sizes of standard buttons in android:

1) almost everything can be controled with how you use the XML. This can all be controled in the area to right, in the ADK. These attributes help you to control almost every aspect.

for example as in the calculator...

you have 4 buttons in a row so you want to add 4 buttons inside of a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Then you can give the a weight of 1 for each button then set their `Width` to `FillParent`. This will auto size the buttons to be displayed in the width of the screen equally.

> Am I better off making my own calc or modify the existing code?

I would never tell someone to recreate the wheel, however, if you do not understand the code well enough to pickup where they left off then this can be an uphill struggle for you. Your best bet if you are having trouble understanding the code given to you or how to modify it, would be to actually post the code in another question and be very specific and ask for example how can I change what this particular button displays and what the result of clicking it would be. This forum depends on the people asking the questions to be clear and concise. If not then questions will closed as fast as they are opened. Generalizations are severely frowned upon on the site.

> In the end, what I am trying to do is make my own scientific calculator but I don't want to spend extra time doing the simple operations.

The best way to answer this is to take a look at how the calculator is assembled in the GUI or Graphical Layout. Try changing a button and what it does. for example make the plus a minus just for the learning curve.

1) look for `, PLUS(" + ",KeypadButtonCategory.OPERATOR)` and notice that is a string for plus. change it to " T " see if it changes in the app. If it does then go into the code. In the code you will find `case CALCULATE:` for for the = sign in the `ENUM` and then inside that you find `evalResult = evaluateResult(true);`. If you follow this you reach:

```
if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.DIV.getText())) {
            result = leftVal / rightVal;
        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MULTIPLY.getText())) {
            result = leftVal * rightVal;

        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.PLUS.getText())) {
            result = leftVal + rightVal;
        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MINUS.getText())) {
            result = leftVal - rightVal;

        }
```

so now you can change `result = leftVal + rightVal;` to `result = leftVal - rightVal;` and you have just changed it. so it will take some time to understand the code but you have to do some trial and error to understand it. I hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: I understand how to do things such as that but my problem lies in editing this code:

Comment: explain what you mean by editing and what you mean by code(my code?)

Comment: this code:http://www.itechcode.com/2012/03/18/create-calculator-in-android-programming/

Comment: ok I saw that code. Now what do you mean by editing it? If your not familiar with XML its best to you the Graphical Layout. What you want to do is make it your own. So you want to use the tutorial to help you understand what YOU want to do not just replicate what they did.

Comment: Thank You for your time. I imported this code into eclipse and I want to improve upon the design i.e. add more operations/simplify fractions in exact form. Am I better off making my own calc or modify the existing code? In the end, what I am trying to do is make my own scientific calculator but I don't want to spend extra time doing the simple operations.

Comment: I just added to my answer.